# How to write this JSON into Elasticsearch Java API?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have the following `JSON` query for Elasticsearch (which works fine) -

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "by_emotion": {
      "terms": {"field": "classifier_emotion"},
      "aggs": {
        "avg_probability": {
          "avg": {"field": "classifier_emotion_probability"}
        },
        "sum_probability": {
          "sum": {"field": "classifier_emotion_probability"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I was trying to rewrite it using the Java API -

```
public AggregationBuilder<TermsBuilder> getClassifierAggregation(String classifierName) {
    String probailityField = classifierName + "_probability";
    return AggregationBuilders.terms("by_class")
        .subAggregation(
            AggregationBuilders.terms("classifier").field(classifierName)
        )
        .subAggregation(
            AggregationBuilders.avg("avg_probability").field(probailityField)
        )
        .subAggregation(
            AggregationBuilders.sum("sum_probability").field(probailityField)
        );
}
```

And then using it as -

```
SearchRequestBuilder request = elasticsearchClient.prepareSearch(index)
        .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
        .setFrom(0)
        .setSize(0)
        .addAggregation(getClassifierAggregation(classifierName));
SearchResponse response = request.execute().actionGet();
```

But I am getting the following exception -

```
org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.AggregationExecutionException: could not find the appropriate value context to perform aggregation [by_class]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I mentioned was wrongly written. Here is the correct one -

```
public TermsBuilder getClassifierAggregation(String classifierName) {
    String probailityField = classifierName + "_probability";
    return AggregationBuilders.terms("by_class").field(classifierName)
        .subAggregation(
            AggregationBuilders.avg("avg_probability").field(probailityField)
        )
        .subAggregation(
            AggregationBuilders.sum("sum_probability").field(probailityField)
        );
}
```